# Some video file extensions are not working for video preview in angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, video

I am working on video preview issue. I am able to show the mp4 file extension video preview. But remaining all video file extensions mpeg, m4v, wmv..etc are not working for video preview code.

I added the all file types in the video src html code, but its working for only mp4 videos.I am using the [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) angular concept for this preview.
I have created the plunker [Video Preview plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/gimZn2RudLYgRWxLrukM?p=preview), you can check my code in the plunker. I got this code from ng2  file upload plugin [ng2 file upload concept](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload/issues/158)

**component code:**

```
filePreview(input : any){
 this.videoPreviewPath  = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl((window.URL.createObjectURL(input.files[0]))); 
}
```

**html code**

```
 <input type="file" (change)="filePreview(input)"
     accept=".mp4,.mpg,.m4v,.flv,.avi,.mov,.wmv,.divx,.f4v,.mpeg,.vob" 
 #input />

<video  controls preload="auto" width="280" height="180" >
  <source [src]='videoPreviewPath' type = 'video/mp4'>
  <source [src]='videoPreviewPath' type = 'video/3gpp'>
  <source [src]='videoPreviewPath' type = 'video/quicktime'>
  <source [src]='videoPreviewPath' type = 'video/x-ms-wmv'>
</video>
```

please can any one help on this. why remaining file extensions are not working for this code.

Comment: At which browsers have you tried to play the video? If `.mp4` video renders, what is issue?

Comment: I tried in chrome. file extensions are not supporting with video src. please can you check my above plunker.

Comment: What is expected result? Note, `.3gp` and `.3g2` are not listed at `accept` attribute value

Comment: Need to show the video preview when we select the video.and need to play the video when we click on the preview

Comment: To show the video preview I am using video mime types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`HTMLMediaElement.canPlayType()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canPlayType), which accepts a `MIME` type as parameter and returns a string value

> - 'probably': The specified media type appears to be playable.
> - 'maybe': Cannot tell if the media type is playable without playing it.
> - '' (empty string): The specified media type definitely cannot be played.

to determine if the `<video>` element can play the media `MIME` type.

At Chromium 59 only `"video/mp4"` returns `"maybe"`, `"video/3gpp"`, `"video/quicktime"`, `"video/x-ms-wmv"`, `"video/x-msvideo"`, `"video/dvd"`, `"video/xvid"`, `"video/x-flv"`
 , `"video/x-f4v"`, and `"video/divx"`  each return an empty string `""`, indicating that the video cannot be played at `<video>` element at Chromium or Chrome browsers.

```js
let mimeTypes = [
  "video/mp4", "video/3gpp", "video/quicktime"
, "video/x-ms-wmv", "video/x-msvideo", "video/mpeg"
, "video/dvd", "video/xvid", "video/x-flv"
, "video/x-f4v", "video/divx"
];

let video = document.createElement("video");

mimeTypes.forEach(type => console.log(type,  video.canPlayType(type)));
```

Comment: thanks for nice clarification, so any other suggestions to show the preview in browsers?

Comment: @SathishKotha Convert the video to an `.mp4` if requirement is to play video at Chrome, Chromium